# Can I connect as a custom user/role to postgresql db?

Tags: .net, database, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

I created a user/role in postgres db and set default search_path to a specific schema. Now what I am trying to achieve is connect to the database using the new user/role and be able to work on that schema for all queries to database.

```
CREATE ROLE ltv_dev WITH PASSWORD '<some password>';
```

So I was hoping if I can connect to the database using a connection string that is for the user/role from a .net core web client using Npgsql.

My previous connection string was.

```
"NpgsqlConnectionStringOptions": {
        "Server": "server_location",
        "Port": 5432,
        "Database": "db_name",
        "UserId": "original_user_id",
        "Password": "pwd"
      }
```

I tried changing the UserId from the previous connection string to the new user/role and the password as well.

My new connection string

```
"NpgsqlConnectionStringOptions": {
        "Server": "server_location",
        "Port": 5432,
        "Database": "db_name",
        "UserId": "ltv_dev",
        "Password": "password_for_the_role"
      }
```

But it did not work.

Is there any way I can connect to the database using a custom user/role from a .net client using Npgsql or is there another approach to solving this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have created a role without LOGIN privilige, the NOLOGIN option is by default in CREATE ROLE, or you can use CREATE USER:

```
CREATE USER ltv_dev PASSWORD '<some password>';
```

you can see it in the documentation

[CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createrole.html)